# Why k-d trees is not used for high dimensional data?

Tags: algorithm

Quoting Wikipedia on k-d tree's page:

> k-d trees are not suitable for efficiently finding the nearest
>   neighbour in high-dimensional spaces. As a general rule, if the
>   dimensionality is k, the number of points in the data, N, should be N>>
>    2k. Otherwise, when k-d trees are used with high-dimensional data, most of the points in the tree will be evaluated and the efficiency is
>   no better than exhaustive search,[11] and approximate
>   nearest-neighbour methods should be used instead.

I don't understand the difference between the dimensionality (k) and the number of points in the data (N) and why it's true the statement about when k-d trees are not convenient.

Comment: k is the number of dimensions (vector components) of the data points. When k is large, the k-D tree is inefficient because the splits do not reduce the mininmum distance effectively and the search degenerates to exhaustion.

Comment: Ok, so if we have an image represented as a vector of 64 bits, we have k=4...but what is N?

Comment: What is the relation between 64 and 4 ???

Comment: Sorry, just a typo: k=64, but what is N?

Comment: The number of vectors, what else ?

Comment: Ok, so in order to have sense with a vector composed by 64 bits we need at least a dataset of 2^64 vectors (wow!).

Comment: "in order to have sense": of course not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`k` is the *dimensionality of your data*, whereas `n` is the *number of points in your data set*. So if your data set consists of 10 million points and each point has 3 dimensions, `k` is 3 and `n` is 10 million.

The reason that k-d trees are unsuitable for finding nearest neighbours in high dimensions is related to the so-called [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality#Nearest_neighbor_search). A k-d tree repeatedly uses a split along a single dimension, but when dealing with high-dimensional data, knowing something about the (Euclidian) distance in one dimension says very little about the distance in the full space.

The reason for wanting a dataset of more than 2<sup>k</sup> is quite intuitive: we split the dataset in two halves of equal size along each dimension. If we have fewer than 2<sup>k</sup> data points, after a while there will be no more data to split! For example, if you have 4 points in 3 dimensions, we can split on x, giving two sets of two points. We split this on y, giving four sets of one point. But now we can't split on z anymore!

Comment: `knowing something about the [Euclidean] distance in one dimension says very little about the distance in the full space` - it gives a lower bound, so proximity in less than all dimensions doesn't imply proximity "in the full space", but _distant_ in even one dimension does rule it out.

Comment: Does kd-tree work slow or does it give low accuracy? Or both ? building kd-tree for high dimensional data takes O(nk) time. Also accuracy might suffer.